# White screen on frontend after bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade, white-screen

I have a strange problem - I get a white screen on the frontend (backend is ok) after running the command: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I have test Magento 2.3.5 system on which I have previously installed new extensions/modules without any problems. I added in a module derived from tutorial by a well known extension provider then went through the procedure of:

php bin/magento module:enable Module_Name
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

The module worked on the backend in that it added a column to the Sales grid as planned but then I noticed a blank screen on the frontend. PHP memory_limit is set to 756M so that shouldn't be the problem.

I kept restoring from backup and trying things and in the end straight after restoring tried just the setup:upgrade command with no new module in place and got the white screen so it was nothing to do with the module.

So have working website then do php bin/magento setup:upgrade then white screen.
Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Once try running cache flush, and  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Can you please check in browser console is there any error, also enable developer mode and check in logs if there are any.

Comment: don't forget about setup compile

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I have already tried cache clean, cache flush, bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
Plus bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB and setup complile in just about every order.

Comment: Have this in Web console:
The resource from “https://swtest.traksafe.co.uk/pub/static/version1615840286/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/jquery/ui.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://swtest.traksafe.co.uk/pub/static/version1615840286/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/jquery/ui.js”.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    makeError https://swtest.traksafe.co.uk/pub/static/version1615840286/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/requirejs/require.js:166
    onScriptError https://swtest.traksafe.co.uk/pub/static/version1615840286/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/requirejs/require.js:1681
require.js:166:17